# Making Drupal's FileField output HTML5 compliant

Tags: drupal, drupal-files

I'm trying to remove the "size" attribute from Drupal's `FileField` output. Right now, it outputs a tag like this:

```
 <input type="file" name="files[image]"  class="form-file" id="edit-image" size="40" />
```

I tried a number of permutations of using `unset()` in a `#pre_render` callback in my custom module, but I just wind up with size="". The attribute itself never goes away, so HTML5 validators continue to complain. Is there another way to accomplish this, or a way to truly ensure that your callback runs last? `$form['mystuff'][] = 'mycallback'` is not doing the trick, and plain old `unset($form['mystuff']['#size'])` runs far too late.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `hook_form_alter()`?

```
function YOUR_THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'YOUR_FORM_ID') { // Selects the form you want        
    $form['YOUR_FIELD_NAME']['#size'] = NULL;
  } 
}
```

With this I've been able to remove size and add HTML5 bits like placeholders etc:

```
$form['name']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('username'));
```

Comment: Obviously change your doctype to HTML too.

Comment: I tried it that way, too. Something keeps putting the attribute back afterwards, and I wind up with size="".